# Cannot compare elements of type. Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15211362/only-primitive-types-or-enumeration-types-are-supported-in-this-context) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15211362/only-primitive-types-or-enumeration-types-are-supported-in-this-context), but I still can't figure why I'm getting this error. both c.NvrId and n.Id are of type `int`

```
var cameras = from c in context.CameraEntities
              join n in context.NetworkVideoRecorderEntities
                  on c.NvrId equals n.Id
                  into cn
              from x in cn.DefaultIfEmpty()
              where listofIds.Contains(c.Id)
              select new Camera
              {
                  Id = c.Id,
                  Name = c.Name,
                  NetworkVideoRecorder = cn == null ? null : new NetworkVideoRecorder
                  {
                      Id = x.Id,
                      Description = x.Description,
                      IP = x.IP,
                  }
              };

return cameras.ToList();
```

Error gets thrown when I perform a `cameras.ToList();`

This is the full error message:

```
Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Models.NetworkVideoRecorderEntity, Asis.Ibss.Net.DataObjects, Version=2014.1.5494.33354, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'. Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported.
```

Comment: Does it work if you remove `cn == null ? null : `?

Comment: As a side note, I think you should check if `x` is null rather than `cn`.

Comment: @RahulSingh ... good spot.

Answer (score 1):

You were doing a null check within the 'select' clause.

> `NetworkVideoRecorder = cn == null ? null : new NetworkVideoRecorder
>                     {
>                         Id = x.Id,
>                         Description = x.Description,
>                         IP = x.IP,
>                     }`

As @RahulSingh pointed out in the comments, I think you are better off checking if x is null rather than checking if cn is null.