# EF - finding items which are not in the list of integers - resulting query doesn't use parameters

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I am using the following method:

```
public PagedResult<PaymentPlanItems> GetPagedRequest(SearchRequest searchRequest, List<int> idsToExclude)
    {
        var list = _dbSetList.AsQueryable();
        if (idsToExclude != null)
        {
            list = list.Where(item => !idsToExclude.Contains(item.ItemId));
        }

        var query = SearchHelper.GetFilteredSearch<PaymentPlanItems>(list, searchRequest);
        var pagedResultMessage = SearchHelper.GetPagedResult(query, searchRequest);
        return pagedResultMessage;
    }
```

where idsToExclude I originally got using this (found from another SO thread):

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchViewModel.ItemsToExclude))
        {
            List<int> idsToExclude = new List<int>(Array.ConvertAll(searchViewModel.ItemsToExclude.Split(','), int.Parse));
            searchViewModel.Result = _paymentPlanItemsAdapter.GetPagedRequest(searchViewModel.SearchRequest, idsToExclude);
        }
```

I then look at the generated query using profile and I see that I get the following as part of my query:

```
WHERE ( NOT ([Extent1].[ItemId] IN (440, 1017)))
```

I don't know if I should be really concerned as my numbers get inserted into the query directly and not as parameters and if I should be, what modifications to this method / approach I should take to make this query use parameters?

Comment: This should be safe. From the security standpoint, it would be concerning if you manually concatenate parameters (mainly strings). Here, EF is escaping everything so there shouldn't be any risk. Is your concern just security or performance as well?

Comment: I think performance too although for this particular table is not a big deal as we don't have too many items normally (I'd say, 10K is the most). But if I'm going to use similar approach for other cases where the table may have lots of rows - is it a concern or not?

Comment: I'm thinking - is it possible to somehow generate a new object from my list on integers and then instead of using simple contains use !Any approach assuming this will get properly executed as parameterized query? So, the little hurdle right now is to get back a list of object from the original list of int?

Comment: I think this shouldn't be an issue security or performance wise. May be a parameterized query should do best, but my guess is that it's not easy to get since the length of the list is variable. It will depend also on the db engine, how frequent is the query, etc.

Comment: As far as I know, that approach has also a drawback that it's going to slow down as the list grows and I also think the number of ids in that form has some SQL Server limitation (need to find this out).

Comment: I've tried  var list = _dbSetList.AsQueryable();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(itemsToExclude))
            {
                var idsToExclude = new List<int>(Array.ConvertAll(itemsToExclude.Split(','), int.Parse)).Select(x => new IdsList{ Id = x }).ToList();
                list = list.Where(item => !idsToExclude.Any(lst=>item.ItemId== lst.Id));
            }  but unfortunately this doesn't work. I'm getting this error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15211362/only-primitive-types-or-enumeration-types-are-supported-in-this-context/15211411

Comment: can you convert this into some kind of "```IN (SUBQUERY)```" query?

Comment: How? What exactly do you propose?